# Why does RestKit produce deeply recursive property mappings?

Tags: restkit

I am trying to map moderately complex JSON into a nested object structure.  The Shops object is recursive, but the ErrorStatus object is not.  However, a debugging breakpoint taken just after the reationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"ErrorStatus" below, shows that entityMapping -> ErrorStatus is deeply recursive through _mutablePropertyMappings.  Unfortunately the debug doesnt seem to support copying, otherwise I would show it here.  Any hint at what's up would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @implementation LLSResponse

    + (RKObjectMapping *)jsonMapping
    {
        RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);    //??? debugging
        RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Networking", RKLogLevelTrace);    //??? debugging
        NSLog(@"===== LLSResponse.jsonMapping/RestKitMapping");


        RKObjectMapping * entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LLSResponse class]];

        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
         [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"ErrorStatus"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"ErrorStatus"
                                                   withMapping:[ErrorStatus jsonMapping]]];
        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
         [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Shops"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"Shops"
                                                   withMapping:[Shops jsonMapping]]];
        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
         [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Events"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"Events"
                                                   withMapping:[Events jsonMapping]]];

        return entityMapping;
    }

    - (NSArray *) getAllEvents
    {
        NSLog(@"============ getAllEvents");
        Events * events = self.events;
        NSArray *allEvents = events.events;
        return allEvents;
    }
    @end


    @implementation ErrorStatus

    + (RKObjectMapping *)jsonMapping
    {
        NSLog(@"===== ErrorStatus.jsonMapping");
        RKObjectMapping * entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ErrorStatus class]];
        [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                            @"@ID" : @"_id",
                                                            @"@Status" : @"Status",
                                                            }];
        return entityMapping;
    }

    @end


    @implementation Events
    + (RKObjectMapping *)jsonMapping
    {
        NSLog(@"===== Events.jsonMapping");
        RKObjectMapping * entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Events class]];
        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
         [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Event"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"Event"
                                                   withMapping:[EventDO jsonMapping]]];    
        return entityMapping;
    }

    @end

    @implementation Shop
    + (RKObjectMapping *)jsonMapping
    {
        NSLog(@"===== Shop.jsonMapping");
        RKObjectMapping * entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Shop class]];

        [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                            @"@ID" : @"_id",
                                                            @"@Title" : @"title",

                                                            }];

        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
            [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Shop"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"Shop"
                                                   withMapping:entityMapping]];
        return entityMapping;
    }

    @end

    @implementation Shops
    + (RKObjectMapping *)jsonMapping
    {
        NSLog(@"===== Shops.jsonMapping");
        RKObjectMapping * entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Shops class]];
        [entityMapping addPropertyMapping:
         [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Shop"
                                                     toKeyPath:@"Shop"
                                                   withMapping:[Shop jsonMapping]]];
        return entityMapping;
    }

    @end
```

I posted a more general question with more code and the JSON in question, but this may capture the essence of the problem. See [RestKit not mapping recursive JSON to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167180/restkit-not-mapping-recursive-json-to-objects)

Comment: Redo both of your questions, preferably to create one well tagged question which asks one thing and shows the mapping, descriptor and JSON associated with that one thing...